# Why this GoogleAPI XML response cannot be deserialized?

Tags: c#, xml, api, windows-phone-8.1, xml-deserialization

I am trying to get the coordinates of an address through Google API. This is my request: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" + "Berlin Hbf (tief)" + "&sensor=true"
and this is the response from Google:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GeocodeResponse>
    <status>OK</status>
    <result>
        <type>transit_station</type>
        <type>point_of_interest</type>
        <type>establishment</type>
        <formatted_address>Berlin Hbf (tief), 10557 Berlin, Germany</formatted_address>
        <address_component>
            <long_name>Berlin Hbf (tief)</long_name>
            <short_name>Berlin Hbf (tief)</short_name>
            <type>point_of_interest</type>
            <type>establishment</type>
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
            <long_name>Mitte</long_name>
            <short_name>Mitte</short_name>
            <type>sublocality_level_1</type>
            <type>sublocality</type>
            <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
            <long_name>Berlin</long_name>
            <short_name>Berlin</short_name>
            <type>locality</type>
            <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
            <long_name>Berlin</long_name>
            <short_name>Berlin</short_name>
            <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
            <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
            <long_name>Germany</long_name>
            <short_name>DE</short_name>
            <type>country</type>
            <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
            <long_name>10557</long_name>
            <short_name>10557</short_name>
            <type>postal_code</type>
        </address_component>
        <geometry>
            <location>
                <lat>52.5253840</lat>
                <lng>13.3692087</lng>
            </location>
            <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
            <viewport>
                <southwest>
                    <lat>52.5240350</lat>
                    <lng>13.3678597</lng>
                </southwest>
                <northeast>
                    <lat>52.5267330</lat>
                    <lng>13.3705577</lng>
                </northeast>
            </viewport>
        </geometry>
        <place_id>ChIJ0SkfA5ZRqEcRo-ThHeCZJl8</place_id>
    </result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

This is the code I am using to deserialize it:

```
string servResp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

try
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GoogleAPI.GeocodeResponse));
    geoCodeResponse = ((GoogleAPI.GeocodeResponse)(serializer.Deserialize(XmlReader.Create(servResp))));
}
    catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

and these are my classes: http://codeshare.io/qGChA

For some reason it crashes with an exception:

> $exception.InnerException  {System.ArgumentException: Illegal
>   characters in path.    at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String
>   path, Boolean checkAdditional)    at System.IO.Path.GetFileName(String
>   path)    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode,
>   FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlRelativePathResolver.OpenStream(Uri
>   uri)} System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}

Why is this?

Comment: I would say this is no XML problem. What is the path you use while accessing the "file" / content ?

Comment: I don't know there are no any files involved..

Comment: Are you sure you are passing a stream to xmlreader ? If your strserverresponse is a string it is expected to be a url. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.xmlreader.create(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, see my updated question.

Comment: You are sure you are passing a stream ? But your code states `string servResp`. ?!?!?

Answer (score 0):

Deserialize method should be provided with a StringReader object, not a string.
The right solution is:

```
string servResp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(servResp);

            try
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GoogleAPI.GeocodeResponse));
                geoCodeResponse = ((GoogleAPI.GeocodeResponse)(serializer.Deserialize(XmlReader.Create(stringReader))));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

[`XmlReader.Create(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k674bf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) reads XML from *URI specified by the input parameter*.  You're passing your actual XML rather than a URI referring to it.  You need to feed the XML string through a `StringWriter`, as in the following extension method:

```
public static class XmlExtensions
{
    public static T DeserializeXml<T>(this string xmlString)
    {
        using (var reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
        {
            return (T)new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

And then do:

```
        string servResp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        try
        {
            geoCodeResponse = servResp.DeserializeXml<GoogleAPI.GeocodeResponse>();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```